# Why nodejs use magic strings in its core modules willy-nilly?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning nodejs and having previous experience with other {strongly typed} languages I'm suffering a bit finding the reason why there is so much abuse of magic values (mainly strings) in core modules of nodejs.

Just to give an example, let's take the implementation of the `http` module which has classes that extends `EventEmitter` and relies on strings to identify events, such as the `http.Server` class with its `'connection'`, `'connect'` and `'request'` events identifiers.

Is there a reason for that? Isn't there any better way to achieve that (like just using an object for instance)?

Comment: The DOM API, which has established an event model for a much longer time, also uses strings for event types. Related: [event constants for javascript?](/q/8438550/4642212).

Comment: Also see: [Symbols should be allowed as Event types](//github.com/whatwg/dom/issues/331).

Comment: @SebastianSimon waiting for that implementation. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a reason for that?

ECMAScript does not have enumerations. To model them, one would have to use one of the available types, namely numbers, strings or objects (or symbols, though they're younger than NodeJS). Now "magic strings" are far better than "magic numbers" or "magic empty objects".

Comment: What about declaring an object or a class type for the purpose of identifying events? Wouldn't this be a better approach than just spamming magic values everywhere? Also may you elaborate why magic strings are "far better" than magic numbers?

Comment: @underthevoid well, which event does `3` stand for (compared to, "what does `"connect"` stand for)? And sure, NodeJS could've defined `const EVENT = { connect: "connect", ... };`, but that's just introducing a container for whatever magic value

Comment: Also probably the ecosystem moved faster than the NodeJS standard API did, so `"connect"` was already well known and introducing some constants for it would serve little value (as nobody would use them)

Comment: Sure strings are more expressive than numbers, however the problems I had in mind was regarding magic values in general. The way you wrote led me to think that as magic strings are "far better" than magic numbers they are then an acceptable approach to the realm of problems that magic values in general introduce in a code base.

Comment: The question says that the `EventEmitter` class is extended, which suggests that static values could’ve been used there, e.g. `EventEmitter.CONNECT_EVENT === "connect"`. No need for an additional `EVENT` object mapping keys to values. Even the DOM API has such static properties, e.g. `Node.TEXT_NODE === 3` or `Event.CAPTURING_PHASE === 1`, but not for the event names.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I would love to read more about this thinking. May you elaborate it a bit more in an answer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @underthevoid Not sure what you want me to elaborate. For some reason I assumed that the question already hinted at static properties, but now I don’t remember how I made that connection. Anyway, you can run `Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(globalThis)).filter(([ name, { value } ]) => typeof value === "function" && Object.keys(value).filter((key) => (/^[^a-z]*[A-Z][^a-z]*$/).test(key)).length).map(([ name ]) => name)` to get a list of names of JS objects which have these “constant” static properties. There’s also `Range.START_TO_END === 1`, `CSSRule.MEDIA_RULE === 4`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I am not 100 % sure, but the formal definition on the official Node website describes Node as “a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome’s V8 JavaScript engine.”  and v8 was primarily built for the client side i.e web. So, if you look at the [web events](https://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events), you will see this pattern being used. Probably that is  why i think.

Comment: That NodeJS uses V8 instead of another runtime (say SpiderMonkey) is IMO irrelevant to the question. That the NodeJS APIs were modeled after the WebAPIs is however a valid point and should be the core of your answer.

Comment: but the question specifically mentions nodejs that is  why the orientation.

Comment: @code Yes, but the fact that Node is based on V8 is irrelevant.